# Why Spring HandlerExecutionChain has both interceptors and interceptorList?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Why there are array type interceptors and list type interceptorList in spring source `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain`？ Is this necessary?

```java
public class HandlerExecutionChain {

    private final Object handler;

    @Nullable
    private HandlerInterceptor[] interceptors;

    @Nullable
    private List<HandlerInterceptor> interceptorList;

    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look in [the source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/9036cc689912b9a3dea8707fc5de5eb78ef4344b/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExecutionChain.java#L122) you will see that only `HandlerInterceptor[] interceptors` is only returned outside the `HandlerExecutionChain` in:

```java
public HandlerInterceptor[] getInterceptors() {
```

Also you can look at `List<HandlerInterceptor> initInterceptorList(` that is used to create `List<HandlerInterceptor> interceptorList`. It looks like the `interceptorList` is collection that helps in creating  the `interceptors` array that later is exposing outside.